# Is there a way to get the OHLC of first and second candle of the day in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, trading, algorithmic-trading

I want the OHLC data of the first and second candle of the day in 5 minute time frame. That is, OHLC of 1st 5 min candle and OHLC of 2nd 5 min candle. I have tried the following.

```
is_newbar(res) =>
    t = time(res)
    change(t) != 0 ? 1 : 0

is_newbar1(res) =>
    t = time(res)
    change(t[1]) != 0 ? 1 : 0

newbar = is_newbar("D")
newbar1 = is_newbar1("D")

var float s1 = na
var float s2 = na
var float s3 = na
var float s4 = na
if newbar
    s1 := low
    s2 := high
    s3 := close
    s4 := open

var float s11 = na
var float s12 = na
var float s13 = na
var float s14 = na
if newbar1
    s11 := low
    s12 := high
    s13 := close
    s14 := open
```

After getting these values I am coding for range breakouts like if s13>s3 then do something. The problem is, in real-time it not only takes the 1st two candle values, but considers every candle OHLC and tries to match the if condition everytime. I want it to execute once and display the result. Please help me out.

Comment: I am using version4

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I usually use for selling and buying at a specific time. I used this script for backtesting a BTST strategy. Since you want to trigger the buy/sell actions at a specific time you can actually provide the hour and minutes in the scripts. All you need to make sure is that there is a close point at your desired point, basically, keep the resolution smaller than 5 mins and can give a candle at 5 min interval. (in your case it is 1 min and 5 mins candles)

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © SaiyadRasikh
//@version=4
strategy("Stackoverflow_Answer", overlay = true)

// Allowing only Long entries
strategy.risk.allow_entry_in(strategy.direction.long)

//Considering Nifty as the Index
var s_close = 0.0

if (hour(time) == 09 and minute(time) == 20)
    s_close := close
    
buy = s_close > s_close[1] //Condition where second candleis close is higher than first candle close, Then enter the trade
sell = s_close < s_close[1]

strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, when = buy,comment="Buy")
strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, when = sell,comment="Sell")
```

You will get something like this with the above code as a plot.[image]

Comment: can you provide the full code, so I can tweak and test it?

Comment: Edited my code, i guess this is what you were trying to implement. Use a 5 min candle and then close[1] will give you close value of previous candle. Using that you can trigger your condition. Hepe this will help. Peace!

Comment: This is great. But one little change needed. Right now it takes position right after the candle is closed. Can we make it like, if the high or low of that candle is broken then only buy/sell? can you help me out here?

Comment: the you should use high of the candle in question, if its high is higher than price to be broken only then buy/sell. @PrasannaKumarSR

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Prasanna Kumar S R,

Instead of using an if and save the value into a variable, try to use "valuewhen".
I have been working on a strategy where I have to save the first handle high. I used the following code
'''d = valuewhen( (is_first), high, 0 )''' when i plot the "d" its constant till end of the day.